# Error Creating Bean - Autowiring of dependencies failed

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting this error when I run my spring-mvc application :

```
Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.config.SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.dao.PersonDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.config.SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

I have also checked the dependencies in  my **pom.xml**

```
<!-- Spring -->
<spring-framework.version>4.2.4.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

<!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
<hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Apart from this, I have specified `${spring-framework.version}` and `${hibernate.version}` in the version of all the dependencies

//////////////////////////////Spring Configuration//////////////

```
package com.config;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

import com.model.Person;
import com.service.PersonService;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({ "com.*" })

@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Autowired
    private PersonService ps;

    @Bean @Autowired
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Person.class);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myschema");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin123");
        return dataSource;
    }
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
                "/resources/*");
    }
    @Bean @Autowired
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver res = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        res.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        res.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return res;
    }


    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default.directory_provider", "org.hibernate.search.store.impl.FSDirectoryProvider");
        properties.put("hibernate.search.default.indexBase", "H:/MyWorkspace/MainAssignment3/indexes");
        return properties;
    }
    @Bean @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

     @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("messages");
            return messageSource;
        }



}
```

///////////////////////////////////POM////////////////////////////////

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>MainAssignment3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.1.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> 
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version> </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId> <artifactId>jta</artifactId> 
            <version>1.1</version> </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>


        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
</dependency>


        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

///////////////////////////////DAO File//////////////////////////////

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;




import com.model.Person;

public interface PersonDAO {
    public void save(Person p);

    public List<Person> list();

    public void updatePerson(Integer id);

    public Person getPersonById(int id);

    public void removePerson(Integer id);

    public void indexPersons() throws Exception;

    public List<Person> searchForPerson(String searchText) throws Exception;

}
```

//////////////////////////DAO Impl///////////////////////////

```
package com.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.hibernate.search.FullTextSession;
import org.hibernate.search.Search;
import org.hibernate.search.query.dsl.QueryBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.model.Person;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO, java.io.Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger logger = (Logger) LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(PersonDAOImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    public void save(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = s.beginTransaction();
        s.saveOrUpdate(p);
        tx.commit();
        s.close();

        System.out.println("Record successfully inserted");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public List<Person> list() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Person> personsList = session.createQuery("from Person").list();
        for (Person p : personsList) {
            logger.info("Person List::" + p);
        }
        return personsList;

    }

    public void updatePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory()
                .openSession();
        Person p = new Person();
        Person person = session.get(Person.class, p.getId());


        //Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Person");
        person.setName(p.getName()); // modify the loaded object somehow
        session.update(person);
        //t.commit();
        session.close();

    }

    public Person getPersonById(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        logger.info("Person loaded successfully, Person details=" + p);
        return p;
    }

    public void removePerson(Integer id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

//      Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        Person p = (Person) session.load(Person.class, new Integer(id));
        session.delete(p);
//      t.commit();
        logger.info("Person deleted successfully, person details=");

    }
    @Transactional
    public void indexPersons() throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          try
          {
             Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

             FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
             fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
             throw e;
          }
       }

    public List<Person> searchForPerson(String searchText) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try
          {
             Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

             FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

             QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
               .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Person.class).get();
             org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
               .keyword().onFields("name", "address", "salary","gender")
               .matching(searchText)
               .createQuery();

             org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = 
                fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Person.class);

             List<Person> results = hibQuery.list();
             return results;
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
             throw e;
          }
       }


    }
```

Comment: does anyone have any idea about this?

Comment: I am still not getting it. I also updated the dependencies. I also applied the annotations again

Comment: Could you show us your Spring configuration and dependencies from pom.xml?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. just a moment

Comment: I have updated my question with pom.xml and the SpringConfig.java file. Thanks a lot for your response.

Comment: I also tried removing the Autowired and Bean annotations and re-appliying them. I am still getting the same error/

Comment: Am I missing the '@Bean' in some other class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html) you should update your Spring dependency to 4.3 if you want to use Hibernate 5.2.

Also you have to correct dependencies for Hibernate search (it's releases are different then Hibernate's core).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I updated the spring version to 4.3.1. Now, the error is Error creating bean with name 'springConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ps': Error creating bean with name 'PersonService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pdao': Error creating bean with name 'personDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory': No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: Could you update your question and post source of `com.dao.PersonDAOImpl`?

Comment: Which Means the PersonDao,java file??

Comment: Not interface, but the implementation. So `PersonDAOImpl.java`.

Comment: Yes. I just added that

Comment: I tried debugging it. The error is in the 'return sessionfactory' line

Comment: But if I don't return the session factory object, what should I return?

Comment: Any new suggestions?? Any idea where the problem might have occurred?

Comment: What is the error message in the 'return sessionfactory' line, as you mentioned?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121517/discussion-between-marek-jeszka-and-nishil).

Comment: The same : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037854/error-creating-bean-autowiring-of-dependencies-failed