# Hibernate Version Compatibilty

Tags: hibernate, maven

I have developed a spring mvc+hibernate CRUD application

I also have the Hibernate search functionality in it.

I seem to be having a dependency conflict in the Hibernate versions.

**Errors :**

```
1.org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springConfig': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.config.SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

2.org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.config.SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

I referred https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix

But Nothing works.

//////////////////////////////////////My pom.xml//////////////////////////

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
    <artifactId>MainAssignment3</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    <!--    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
         -->

        <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
            <version>5.1.0.Final</version> </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId> 
            <version>5.5.2.Final</version> </dependency>
        <!-- <exclusions> <exclusion> <artifactId> hibernate-commons-annotations 
            </artifactId> <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId> </exclusion> <exclusion> 
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
            </exclusion> </exclusions> -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
</dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId> 
            <version>5.5.4.Final</version> </dependency> -->
        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
            <version>4.12</version> </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037854/error-creating-bean-autowiring-of-dependencies-failed/39074759) you should correct versions of dependencies.

`hibernate-entitymanager` is released together with core Hibernate libraries, so it should have 5.2.1.Final version (variable `${hibernate.version}` in your case).

`hibernate-search` is released independently, but you should update it's version and not use 5 year old library. Current stable is 5.5.4.Final.

Comment: I am still getting the error : HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet dispatcher threw exception

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springConfig': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in com.config.SpringConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Comment: I have specified the 5.2.1 version for Hibernate, 4.3.2 version for spring, and the same version for 'hibernate-search-engine' and 'hibernate-search-orm' : 5.5.4.

Comment: My current error, after updating dependencies : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;

Comment: Any suggestions? @Marek

Comment: Your jpa version (1.0.2) is obsolete. I don't think you need it anyway, since hibernate depends on it.

Comment: so I should remove the hibernate-jpa dependency?

Comment: Should I remove this? <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>